# Handling spawn thru thread in tcl

Tags: multithreading, tcl, spawn

I am trying to handle spawn process thru thread , but its throwing error "invalid command" .
But without thread its working fine .

```
set listner [thread::create {
package require Expect
proc router_config {s filename} {
set command_router "{Password: } {abc@123\r}
                    {Router>} {en\r}
                    {Password: } {abc@123\r}"
 spawn telnet 1.1.1.1 
foreach {exp_prompt send_cmd} $command_router {
    expect "$exp_prompt"
    exp_send "$send_cmd"
}
return 1
}
[thread::wait]
}]
set commandString "xyz"
eval [subst {thread::send -async $listner \
    {router_config 0 [list $commandString ]}}]

puts "--------->> releasing thread [thread::id] [thread::release]"

exit 0
```

Please suggest some way to handle .

Comment: Could you maybe try adding `package require Thread` at the biginning?

Comment: what `invalid command`? `thread::create`? Ohh, and expect does not work very well with threads.

Comment: Hi Jerry , tried that .. still same issue

Comment: Hi Johannes , Is their a way out for this, my main objective is to kill the telnet thread/process once by script execution is done ..

Comment: `[thread::wait]` in brackets? That's _very unlikely to be correct_ as the result of `thread::wait` is an empty string and that's never (well, hardly ever) the name of a command.

Comment: Re-ran the code after removing brackets , still same error